# How do I delete files of certain extension that don't have a given string in their filename?

Tags: command-line, rm

I have a directory with files of many extensions in it. I would like to recursively delete `*.srt` files (and `*.srt` files only) which *don't end* with `-en.srt` (where `srt` is an extension). I've come up with the following solution and it seems to work fine, however, I'd like to know whether it is 100% correct.

```
find . -name "*.srt" ! -name "*-en.srt" -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**! -- First read the answer completely then use it if you like it -- !**

Your command is correct, however there is no need to use `-rf` as `rm` parameters. because you are removing files and not directories.

Another clear way to write it is (it's almost same as your command):

```
find -name '*.srt' -and -not -name '*-en.srt' -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
```

or as @steeldriver suggested you can use:

```
find -name '*.srt' -and -not -name '*-en.srt' -type f -ok rm '{}' \;
```

It will ask for your permission to remove each founded file.

You can also use `-delete` instead of `rm {} \;` however  be aware of its dangers:

> Don't  forget  that the find command line is evaluated as an expres‐
>                 sion, so putting -delete first will make find try to  delete  everything  below
>                 the  starting  points you specified.  When testing a find command line that you
>                 later intend to use with -delete, you should explicitly specify -depth in order
>                 to  avoid later surprises.  Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully
>                 use -prune and -delete together.

---

It is always a good idea to test what is going to happen before doing the actual job, so I suggest running:

```
find -name '*.srt' -and -not -name '*-en.srt' -type f | grep -i en.srt
```

If it return nothing then the actual command will work without any problem and you are good to go... or even:

```
find -name '*.srt' -and -not -name '*-en.srt' -type f | less
```

to check what's going to be removed.

And do not forget to quote `'{}'`:

> (when find is being invoked from  a  shell)
>                 it  should be quoted (for example, '{}') to protect it from interpretation by shells.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `-rf` is not needed. The part `-exec rm {} \;` can be improved by writing `-exec rm {} +` instead. This way `rm` will be called with as many files as fit into the command line, effectively speeding up the whole process a lot when there are many files.

Comment: @Ravexina As far as I understand the manpage, the `'quotes'` around `{}` are only needed when combined with `-exec … +` (but not with `-exec … \;`). However, it won't do any harm and is generally a good habit.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s do it solely with `bash` globbing: With the `extglob` and `globstar` options enabled,

```bsh
rm **/!(*-en).srt
```

deletes every file ending in `.srt` excluding anything ending in `-en.srt` from the current as well as any subdirectory.
If you‘re not sure about an expansion like this, test by prepending `echo` (see example below).

#### Example

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── 01.srt
├── 02.srt
├── no-en.srt
├── not-en.srt
├── subdir
│   ├── 01.srt
│   ├── 02.srt
│   ├── no-en.srt
│   └── not-en.srt
└── unrelated.png
$ shopt -s extglob globstar
$ echo rm **/!(*-en).srt
rm 01.srt 02.srt subdir/01.srt subdir/02.srt
$ rm **/!(*-en).srt
$ tree
.
├── no-en.srt
├── not-en.srt
├── subdir
│   ├── no-en.srt
│   └── not-en.srt
└── unrelated.png
```

#### Explanations

- `**/` – with the `globstar` option enabled this matches any number of directories and subdirectories
- `!(*-en)` – with the `extglob` option enabled this matches anything except the given pattern, so anything not ending in `-en`